# camera calibration service not available (specific driver for VRMagic)

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-driver, services, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I am using "camera calibration" node to calibrate a stereo system based on a VRMagic D3 stereo camera.
The driver I am using to obtain the images from the camera is "vrmagic_ros_bridge_server".
My launch file is:

```
<launch>

    <node  pkg="vrmagic_ros_bridge_server" name="vrmagic_ros_bridge_server_node" type="vrmagic_ros_bridge_server_node" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <param name="pub_name" type="str" value="/img_pub" />
        <param name="ip_smartcam" type="str" value="172.16.205.100" />
        <param name="port_smartcam" type="int" value="1234" />
    </node>

    <node  pkg="tekniker_image_proc" name="publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node_1" type="publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <param name="image_input_topic" type="str" value="/img_pub1" />
        <param name="camera_info_input_topic" type="str" value="/img_pub1_camera_info" />
        <param name="image_output_topic" type="str" value="/left" />
        <param name="camera_info_output_topic" type="str" value="/camera_info" />
        <param name="frame_id" type="str" value="camera_d3_0" />
        <param name="workspace" type="str" value="stereo" />
    </node>
    
  <node  pkg="tekniker_image_proc" name="publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node_2" type="publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node" respawn="false" output="screen">
        <param name="image_input_topic" type="str" value="/img_pub2" />
        <param name="camera_info_input_topic" type="str" value="/img_pub2_camera_info" />
        <param name="image_output_topic" type="str" value="/right" />
        <param name="camera_info_output_topic" type="str" value="/camera_info" />
        <param name="frame_id" type="str" value="camera_d3_0" />
        <param name="workspace" type="str" value="stereo" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

I have remapped the images to a common workspace, and the following topics:

```
/img_pub1
/img_pub1_camera_info
/img_pub2
/img_pub2_camera_info
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/stereo/camera_info
/stereo/left
/stereo/left/compressed
/stereo/left/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/left/compressed/parameter_updates
/stereo/left/compressedDepth
/stereo/left/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/left/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/stereo/left/theora
/stereo/left/theora/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/left/theora/parameter_updates
/stereo/right
/stereo/right/compressed
/stereo/right/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/right/compressed/parameter_updates
/stereo/right/compressedDepth
/stereo/right/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/right/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/stereo/right/theora
/stereo/right/theora/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/right/theora/parameter_updates
```

The services that I have available are:

```
/publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node_1/get_loggers
/publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node_1/set_logger_level
/publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node_2/get_loggers
/publish_image_and_info_to_common_ws_node_2/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
/stereo/left/compressed/set_parameters
/stereo/left/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/stereo/left/theora/set_parameters
/stereo/right/compressed/set_parameters
/stereo/right/compressedDepth/set_parameters
/stereo/right/theora/set_parameters
/vrmagic_ros_bridge_server_node/get_loggers
/vrmagic_ros_bridge_server_node/set_logger_level
```

Unfortunately, when I use the "camera_calibration" node, I have the following error:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.024 right:=/stereo/right left:=/stereo/left right_camera:=/right left_camera:=/left
('Waiting for service', '/left/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found
('Waiting for service', '/right/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found
```

Which is obvious, because my vrmagic camera driver is not providing that services. If I use "--no-service-check" flag, the terminal get blocked and I obtain no results.

I know this issue has appeared more times on the forums, and all the answers where related to solutions changing or modifying the camera driver to obtain results, but, what if the driver that we are using does NOT provide that services in anyway?
It is not possible to calibrate cameras without using stardard camera drivers?

I would appreciate any king of help a lot...

Thank you,

Alberto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238730/camera-calibration-service-not-available-(specific-driver-for-vrmagic)/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

set_camera_info is the service that "talks" between ROS and the camera driver to set calibration params. No, I don't *think* it is possible to use a nonstandard driver.

It's not terribly difficult to modify a camera driver, especially an open source one. See [camera_info_manager](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_info_manager) (especially the example at the bottom) for help on that.

If you're not up to changing the driver, you might be able to use another calibration setup (through OpenCV, for example) and then c[onvert that output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736558/using-ros-camera-calibration-in-opencv) to a ROS-compatible yaml file

---

Originally posted by [moates](https://answers.ros.org/users/27359/moates/) with karma: 36 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0